# How to emulate an RFID tag with the RC522

Tags: rfid

Is it possible to emulate an RFID tag with the [RC522](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/MFRC522)? (Spec sheet: [nxp MFRC522.pdf](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf))
I want the RC522 to act like a NTAG213 nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf and to be read/write by other readers/writers.
Are there libraries for that purpose?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Arduino.SE site. To better help people answer your query you need to enhance your question with more information. At present it is not clear what you wish to achieve. Can you provide a usage example and more detail about what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Looking at the datasheet, card emulation is not a feature provided by the RC522.

Another popular chip, the [PN532](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/pn532ds.pdf), does seem to indicate support for that feature, however, looking at the most popular [library for this chip](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532) from Adafruit, it does not implement this feature. Another [library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532) from Seeed, does seem to implement it, but it looks rather limited as to which cards can be emulated, and the library itself hasn't been updated in a while.